# Can I see percentage answer rate for a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, statistics

I would like to see what percentage of a tag has been answered. Can I do this? How?

Comment: [Top users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/math/topusers) tells you the proportion of unanswered questions in the last 7 days, 30 days, and overall. The rest is subtraction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On any given tag page, you'll find a 'top users' link:

[image: top users link]

Click that and you'll not only find stats on the top users for that tag, but also the unanswered percentages:

[image: python answer stats]

To get the percentage of *answered* questions instead, simply subtract from 100%.

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to see the percentage of answered questions across all tags, you can [use the data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/100634/121282/percentage-answer-rate-per-tag).

Comment: wow, I never know that site exists! Quite ironic that it is 'offline for maintance' 3 minutes after you posted your question...

Comment: @WouterJ You're kidding me, I hope my query didn't kill it! Wait, it looks like it's working. Might have been a hiccup?

Comment: now, it works here too. (how do you mention your name, I cannot seem to get it working..)

Comment: @WouterJ Just type `@` and start typing a name. The owner of a post is automatically notified of comments though and will not come up on the autocomplete list. Try typing `@D` for example in the comments box for your question.

Comment: I know that, but if I typ `@lc` or `@lc.` it gets removed (looks like it cannot handle the dot in your name or something?)

Comment: @WouterJ Probably a side effect because I'm the owner of the post and always notified? I get mentioned all the time so there's no issue with the dot :) (Long story - I used to have a two-letter username before they were illegal, but at one point I started getting weird errors until I added a third character)

Comment: @lc. You can `@`-mention the OP if somebody else participated in the discussion, but not while you and the OP are the only ones. (Should perhaps better have pinged Wouter, but that wouldn't illustrate the point.)

Comment: @WouterJ See above.

Comment: @DanielFischer Interesting. I didn't know it was that smart

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think it also works the other way: before I commented here, Wouter would have been notified of your comments even without you `@`-mentioning him. The idea seems to be that while only two participants are in a conversation, it's clear each replies to the other. Once a third enters, it can be useful to indicate who you're replying to.

Comment: @lc. your query is great - but it's missing some important things, such as filtering out tag synonyms (which over time will have higher accept rates of any tag type), and sorting the results. So, I made my own query in case you are interested in some more statistics: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/100653/121301/large-tags-w-high-accept-percentage

Comment: Also a great answer +1 . The other answer is a bit more straight forward so got the accepted vote. But really good to know that site exists.